# In FOL, can we define equality for two predicate symbols?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

In FOL, I think equality is always used for two variable or constant symbols. Can we define equality for two predicate symbols? If not, why? (Do we need higher order logic to use such a concept?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In FOL, can we define equality for two predicate symbols?

NO. In first-order logic, equality is defined between "objects" (referred by *terms*, i.e. individual variables and constants) and not between "properties" (referred by predicate symbols).

In Second-order logic, instead, we can define equality between predicates :

> $P = Q \leftrightarrow \forall x (P(x) \leftrightarrow Q(x))$.

Comment: Thank you. But I have one more question. What is the reason why we can not  translate this definition into FOL??  Since $\forall x (P(x) \leftrightarrow Q(x))$ is a well-formed formula in FOL. So, we can think $P = Q $ as its abbreviation? My question is  although $P=Q$ is not a  well-formed formula in FOL,  whether we can use such a concept in FOL.

Comment: @amoogae - the RHS formula is Ok, but we cannot write $P=Q$ because in FOL $=$ is a binary *relation* symbol and we have to use it according to the rules of syntax. But we may circumvent the difficulty because - due to the Replacement Th - if we have proved $∀x(P(x)↔Q(x))$ we may replave $P(x)$ with $Q(x)$ (and vice versa) in more general contexts.